# How to submit a form contained in jQuery dialog by clicking "No" button present on the same jQuery-UI dialog pop-up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-dialog

I've following HTML and jQuery code of dialog:
HTML code which is to be shown in a jQuery-UI dialog:

```
<div id="favouriteQuestion" class="c-popup" style="display:none;">
  <div class="error_msg" id="report_error" style="text-align:center; margin-top:5px;">
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>  
  <form name="add_favourite_question_form" id="add_favourite_question_form" class="login_box" method="post" action="favourite_question.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_submitted" id="form_submitted" value="yes"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="op" id="op" value="add"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="fav_que_id" id="fav_que_id"/>
    <table class="trnsction_details" width="100%" cellpadding="5">
      <tbody>    
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p>Do you want to add this question as your favourite question?</p>
          </td>
          <td></td>            
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" name="yes" value="Yes" class="add_fav_que_yes" class="buttonin"/>
            <input type="button" name="no" value="No" class="add_fav_que_no" class="buttonin"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>  
</div>
```

Now the jQuery code to show this dialog pop-up:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#favouriteQuestion").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal:true,
    title: "Add To Favourite Question",
    width: 400,                     
    close:{
    }           
    });
});
$(document).on("click","a.fav_que", function (e) {
  var que_id = this.id;  

  $("#fav_que_id").val(que_id);
  $("#favouriteQuestion").dialog('open');

  return false;
});
```

After this code the jquery-UI dialog pop-up appears. Further, on clicking Yes button(**class="add_fav_que_yes"**) button I'm submitting the form using AJAX. This is also working fine. But the issue is there when I click on No button(**class="add_fav_que_no"**). It is expected to close the opened dialog box when user clicks on No button(**class="add_fav_que_no"**). So Can anyone guide me in achieving this? If you want any further information I can provide you the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can close dialog box by **onclick** `<input type="button" name="no" value="No" class="add_fav_que_no" class="buttonin" onclick="$("#favouriteQuestion").dialog("close");"/>`

Comment: @Rajesh:Yes man, your trick does well for me.